# Count Word Use in iMessage Messages?

Tags: ios

Could an app count the number of uses of a specific word in an iMessage message? What if the word was in the AutoCorrect dictionary? For example, an app that counted the number of uses of the company name in user's iMessage messages. From what I have researched so far, the answer seems like no because the messages are secure, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: You can't access the messages send or received by Message.app unless the device is jailbreaken.